# Error in step 5.17.1, installation of Bison of Linux From Scratch

Tags: linux-from-scratch

I'm trying to compile Bison to build Linux From Scratch. My host OS is Ubuntu 18.04. Based on the instructions on [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/bison.html) webpage, upon entering

```
./configure --prefix=/tools
```

I eventually get the error

```
...
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking build system type... config.guess: cannot create a temporary directory in /tmp
configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
```

Other users seem to suggest that I'm missing a dependency. But, I couldn't figure out what it might be that I missed.

I'm clueless as to which build type is referred to in the last line of error and how to fix the error. Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `mkdir /tmp/whatever` to see whether it's really not possible to create a directory in `/tmp`? And a look into `config.log` may give more information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com).

Comment: If there is a general problem creating directories in `/tmp` you can see the error condition (which is *not* necessarily EACCES) with *any* directory name you test. One possible error could be EEXIST why looking into `config.log` makes sense. And, by the way, the word "nonsense" is inappropriate in this context!

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) Look at the INSTALL file in your Bison toplevel directory, 2) try adding this to your "configure" command: `--build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` (Assuming you're running 64-bit Ubuntu, and building a 64-bit LFS)

Comment: @GuidoFlohr, `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/whatever’: Read-only file system` - thanks for pointing out. Another SO post suggests that I can fix it by booting a liveusb and running `sudo mount -o rw,remount /`. I'll try that.

Comment: @ariadnus, if `/tmp` is read-only (I assume you're in a chroot jail?), there is something wrong in the installation setup. Maybe check again that you followed the LFS instructions correctly.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr, I'll check the instructions to see if I missed something. Thanks.

Comment: @paulsm4, I added `--build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` to the configure command. It errored again and suggested that I add `--disable-dependency-tracking`. This time configuration finished without errors and I was able to continue with `make` and `make install` without errors. Not sure, if it will give me errors in the subsequent steps.

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I do when I get stuck is:

```
rm -rf bison-3.4.1
```

then I untar the file and redo the entire process. Sometimes, the tar file downloaded is only faulty. In such cases I would suggest that you re-download the file:

```
cd /mnt/lfs/sources
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bison/bison-3.4.1.tar.xz
```

Also, if the problem persists refer the log files to see where exactly it is getting stuck